# How to replace all non-NaN entries of a dataframe with a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know that you can use `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` to replace all null values with a Series, but is there an easy way to replace all non-null values with a Series?

Alternatively, I have seen `df.loc[~df.isnull()]` for replacing all null values with a single value, but again - is there a way to pass in a Series?

Edit: For example, say I have a DataFrame `df` with a column called `code` which contains some null values and some non-null values. Then say I have a Series called `new_code` which contains only non-null values. I want to replace all of the non-null values in `df['code']` with the values of `new_code` (where the number of non-null values is equal to the length of `new_code`).

Comment: do you have an example you can share?

Comment: It's hard to imagine what you mean with replacing null values in a dataframe with a series. Replacing series with series makes sense, but the former not. Like asked above, can you show an example?

Comment: Does the example I added help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as below.

Since you have not provided a df, I am using my own df (input & output shown). 'f' is the series that has been created.

```
a = df.loc[~df['Age'].isnull()]
b = df.loc[~df['Age'].isnull()].index
f= pd.Series([i for i in range(1,12)], index=b)
df.loc[~df['Age'].isnull(),['Age']]=f
```

**Input**

```
Country     Age
0   USA     NaN
1   EU      15.0
2   China   35.0
3   USA     45.0
4   EU      NaN
5   China   NaN
6   USA     28.0
7   EU      26.0
8   China   78.0
9   USA     65.0
10  EU      53.0
11  China   66.0
12  USA     32.0
13  EU      NaN
14  China   14.0
```

**f**

```
1      1
2      2
3      3
6      4
7      5
8      6
9      7
10     8
11     9
12    10
14    11
```

**Output**

```
Country     Age
0   USA     NaN
1   EU      1.0
2   China   2.0
3   USA     3.0
4   EU      NaN
5   China   NaN
6   USA     4.0
7   EU      5.0
8   China   6.0
9   USA     7.0
10  EU      8.0
11  China   9.0
12  USA     10.0
13  EU      NaN
14  China   11.0
```